# My Xiaomi Mi 10T gets a black/shut off screen at minimum brightness. Is it possible to increment the minimum brightness level?

Tags: miui, screen-brightness

My Xiaomi Mi 10T gets total black screen when setting brighness to minimum - IE: impossible to see anything even in a corner of a dark room - as can be seen in this video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AS8QhZV3vyCTMKLL92hW_4H4jXdzbNMg/view?usp=sharing

Is it possible to increment the *minimum brightness* level?

I checked other old answers regarding this issue and seems they don't apply to this one:
I accidentally slid the brightness to minimum and I couldn't use the phone again! Just had to wipe all my data to recover from this state.

Checking the slider carefully now, it seems it goes "shut down" at about 5%, and that's very dangerous.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the minimum same as 0 or total darkness? Don't slide it that far.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but sliding a brightness control to minimum should not "turn off" the screen. I want to fix this behavior

Comment: Sounds like a glitch in system software. I'd suggest that you report the problem to MI customer care in the meantime.

Comment: Could you [edit] and list the other Q&A on the question body?

Comment: That said, this reminds me of the same issue when I was using an old Nexus 5 on LineageOS 14. Turns out it's just the display, but the touchscreen still works, thus I could swipe the brightness slider from the quick settings panel *with trial-and-error (luckily)*. I didn't find the solution to fix it permanently before it went totally broken though.

Comment: The minimum brightness is a common problem. Some users say it is too high, for others it is too low. In most cases it is simply the question how much light you have in your environment. Check your screen in a totally dark environment and I would assume you will see that the screen is not totally dark. Modern devices have an "extra dark" mode that is disabled by default and prevents users from accidentally set the screen brightness to value that appears as "off" in an indoor daylight environment.

Comment: Maybe use an like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.lower.brightness// You can't overcome ROM glitch easily